# Where should I call API in collection (configurable) android App widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a configurable/reconfigurable collection Widget in this I have to call an API for a list so where can I call API (I need to change API when configuration change).
I am trying to call post-API in the onCreate of Factory class.

I have 2 post-APIs, Both APIs return the same type of class so used the same list and same design file for load data when I change the configuration option from configuration activity I want to call the selected API again. but it didn't work

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class MyWidgetServices : RemoteViewsService() {
    override fun onGetViewFactory(intent: Intent): RemoteViewsFactory {
        return ListViewFactory(this.applicationContext, intent)
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var repo: WidgetRepo

    @Inject
    lateinit var prefs: PrefUtil

    inner class ListViewFactory(context: Context, intent: Intent) :
        RemoteViewsFactory {
        private val mContext: Context = context
        private val mAppWidgetId: Int = intent.getIntExtra(
            AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
        )

        private var list: MutableList<PendingResModel> = mutableListOf()
        private var count: Long = 0
        val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(mContext)

        override
        fun onCreate() {
            // Since we reload the cursor in onDataSetChanged() which gets called immediately after
            // onCreate(), we do nothing here.
            this.hashCode().toString().logE()
            if (prefs.showInProgress) {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    repo.inProgress()?.let {
                        it.data?.let {
                            list.addAll(it)
                            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(
                                mAppWidgetId,
                                R.id.lv_order
                            )
                        }
                        it.meta?.let { meta ->
                            count = meta.totalDataCount ?: 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    repo.toConfirm()?.let {
                        it.data?.let {
                            list.addAll(it)
                            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(
                                mAppWidgetId,
                                R.id.lv_order
                            )
                        }
                        it.meta?.let { meta ->
                            count = meta.totalDataCount ?: 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }

        override fun onDestroy() {
            list.clear()
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }


        @SuppressLint("RemoteViewLayout")
        override fun getViewAt(position: Int): RemoteViews {
            val rv = RemoteViews(mContext.packageName, Layouts.row_widget)
            val views = RemoteViews(mContext.packageName, R.layout.layout_widget)
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_count, count.toString())
            Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(list[position].user.profile)
                .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Bitmap,
                        transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                    ) {
                        rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.iv_widget_profile, resource)
                    }

                    override fun onLoadFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
                        super.onLoadFailed(errorDrawable)
                    }

                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeHolder: Drawable?) {
                    }
                })

            rv.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_id, list[position].id)
            rv.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_name, list[position].user.name)
            return rv
        }

        override fun getLoadingView(): RemoteViews? {
            // We aren't going to return a default loading view in this sample
            return null
        }

        override fun getViewTypeCount(): Int {
            // Technically, we have two types of views (the dark and light background views)
            return 1
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onDataSetChanged() {
        }
    }
}
```

this is the updateAppWidget function that is called in onUpdate of a widgetprovider class

```
    internal fun updateAppWidget(
         context: Context,
         appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
         appWidgetId: Int,
         text: String = "In progress"
) {
    val serviceIntent = Intent(context, MyWidgetServices::class.java)
    serviceIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
    serviceIntent.data = Uri.parse(serviceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))
    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.layout_widget)
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_title, text)
    views.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.lv_widget, serviceIntent)
    views.setEmptyView(R.id.lv_widget, R.id.empty_view)
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
}
```

and here is the code of change configuration from the configuration activity

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
super.onClick(v)
when (v) {
    binding.tvProgress -> {
        prefs.showInProgress = true
        updateAppWidget(
            this@ConfigureActivity,
            appWidgetManager,
            appWidgetId,
            text = "In Progress"
        )
        // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
        val resultValue = Intent()
        
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
    appWidgetId)
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue)
        finish()

    }
    binding.tvConfirm -> {
        prefs.showInProgress = false
        updateAppWidget(this@ConfigureActivity, 
      appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, text = "To Confirm")
        val resultValue = Intent()
        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue)
        finish()
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution I called APIs in onDataSetChanged instead of onCreate and take a global boolean variable to manage the recall APIs

```
   override fun onDataSetChanged() {
            if (AppConstants.Misc.isRefreshWidget) {
                list.clear()
                if (prefs.showInProgress) {
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        repo.inProgress()?.let {
                            it.data?.let {
                                list.addAll(it)
                                appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(
                                    mAppWidgetId,
                                    R.id.lv_order
                                )
                            }
                            it.meta?.let { meta ->
                                count = meta.totalDataCount ?: 0
                            }
                            AppConstants.Misc.isRefreshWidget = false
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                        repo.toConfirm()?.let {
                            it.data?.let {
                                list.addAll(it)
                                appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(
                                    mAppWidgetId,
                                    R.id.lv_order
                                )
                            }
                            it.meta?.let { meta ->
                                count = meta.totalDataCount ?: 0
                            }
                            AppConstants.Misc.isRefreshWidget = false

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and change this global variable (isRefreshWidget) on the click of configuring activity's button or whenever you want to call api